# How to add youtube playlist with video in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, youtube

I need to add Youtube playlist with Youtube player in my flutter application.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter) plugin and see if it fits your use case. The plugin doesn't seem to support playlist URLs directly, but you can create a `List<String> videoURls` containing all the video URLs you need for the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

Use the https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart package:

```
var yt = YoutubeExplode();

// Get playlist metadata.
var playlist = await yt.playlists.get('xxxxx');
```